# Display Yes and No buttons instead of OK and Cancel in Confirm box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create yes/no/cancel box in javascript instead of ok/cancel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110825/how-to-create-yes-no-cancel-box-in-javascript-instead-of-ok-cancel)

In a Confirm message box, how can I change the buttons to say "Yes" and "No" instead of "OK" and "Cancel"? Is there some way to accomplish this using jQuery/Javascript? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Thanks Donut. for making edit my question.

Comment: @Felix: It is not an exact duplicate, as the answers to the previous question did not mention how to do this with JQuery, only that it is possible. The answers here could be merged in that question, though.

Comment: @PaloEbermann: Well, there is a link to jQuery dialog. I think we can expect from developers that they read documentation (if they know where to find it). It's still a duplicate, the question is about exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 14):

Create your own confirm box:

```
<div id="confirmBox">
    <div class="message"></div>
    <span class="yes">Yes</span>
    <span class="no">No</span>
</div>
```

Create your own `confirm()` method:

```
function doConfirm(msg, yesFn, noFn)
{
    var confirmBox = $("#confirmBox");
    confirmBox.find(".message").text(msg);
    confirmBox.find(".yes,.no").unbind().click(function()
    {
        confirmBox.hide();
    });
    confirmBox.find(".yes").click(yesFn);
    confirmBox.find(".no").click(noFn);
    confirmBox.show();
}
```

Call it by your code:

```
doConfirm("Are you sure?", function yes()
{
    form.submit();
}, function no()
{
    // do nothing
});
```

You'll need to add CSS to style and position your confirm box appropriately.

Working demo: [jsfiddle.net/Xtreu](http://jsfiddle.net/Xtreu/)

Comment: this not work any way please change code or give more description about this.

Comment: @jubinPatel - Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Xtreu/

Comment: this confirm box doesnt disable the rest of the screen as normal confirm box does. even when the confirm box appears , I am able to press the button "Delete My Data" again

Comment: @ALBI - This update to my jsfiddle adds an overlay to hide the page:  http://jsfiddle.net/Xtreu/269/  I added the overlay with JavaScript, but you could also add it to the HTML and show/hide it with JavaScript like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Xtreu/270/.

Answer (score 13):

If you switch to the jQuery UI Dialog box, you can initialize the buttons array with the appropriate names like:

```
$("#id").dialog({
  buttons: {
    "Yes": function() {},
    "No": function() {}
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to change the content of the buttons in the dialog displayed by the `confirm` function. You can use Javascript to create a dialog that looks similar.

Answer (score 2):

There is the Jquery alert [plugin](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/#demo)

```
$.alerts.okButton = ' Yes ';
$.alerts.cancelButton = ' No ';
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it's not possible to change the content of the buttons, at least not easily. It's fairly easy to have your own custom alert box using [JQuery UI though](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Answer (score 2):

An example using jQuery UI dialog: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/qqkGA/ as well as UI's own demo: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation