# Add Yes and No buttons on jQuery confirmation box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want "Yes" and "No" buttons on a confirmation box without using jQuery UI Dialog.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't change Javascript's standart confirmation box buttons.

I suggest you to use [Jquery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Answer (score 8):

The [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) is a very flexible and powerful tool for that. Here's an example of how to ask the user if he wants to delete something:

```
<div id="dialog_box" style="display: none;">
    Really delete?
</div>
<button class="delete_btn">Delete</button>

<script>
$('.delete_btn').click(function(){
$('#dialog_box').dialog({
  title: 'Really delete this stuff?',
  width: 500,
  height: 200,
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,
  draggable: false,
  buttons: [{
  text: 'Yep, delete it!',
  click: function(){
      //delete it
    }
  },
  {
  text: 'Nope, my bad!',
  click: function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  }]
});
});

</script>
```

**//EDIT:**

Sorry, it was not quite clear from your original question that you do not want to use the jQuery Dialog (but why tag the question with jquery/jquery-ui then?).

AFAIK, there is no other way to accomplish what you want to do. Also, keep in mind, that the text of the native JavaScript dialog box also takes care of the browser language and other local factors. So it might not always be a good idea to mess around with that.

Answer (score 6):

Well, yes and no (no pun intended). You can use this:

```
if (confirm("Would you like an alert?")) {
    alert("Here you go!");
}
```

The **[`confirm` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.confirm)** will return `true` if the user pressed "OK", or `false` if "Cancel" was pressed. This is pure JavaScript (DOM level 0), so **all browsers support this**.

However, as far as I know, there is no way to customize the labels of the buttons. So you're stuck with the defaults ("**Cancel**" and "**OK**" on most browsers, if set to English).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, but only in IE: [Javascript Confirm popup Yes, No button instead of OK and Cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823790/javascript-confirm-popup-yes-no-button-instead-of-ok-and-cancel)
AFAIK Other browsers doesn't support it

```
<script language="javascript">
    function window.confirm(str) {
        execScript('n = msgbox("' + str + '","4132")', "vbscript");
        return (n == 6);
    }
</script>
```

If you don't want jQueryUI, but think of a plugin - try http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/#demo (also mentioned in linked answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can't change confirm box text but you can create your own.

see here example :- [Display Yes and No buttons instead of OK and Cancel in Confirm box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445946/display-yes-and-no-buttons-instead-of-ok-and-cancel-in-confirm-box)

i think you will get the idea about custom confirm box.