# Custom javascript/jquery dialog in mobile app not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, jquery-mobile, dialog

I am using Eclipse and have gotten JQM type dialogs to work in simple applications running in an AVD and have also used the approach given in to get a workable custom dialog:

[Display Yes and No buttons instead of OK and Cancel in Confirm box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445946/display-yes-and-no-buttons-instead-of-ok-and-cancel-in-confirm-box)

In my proper application, however, I cannot get any form of dialog box to display.

Most of the javascript code for my application is contained in an "on pageshow" type function, i.e. within:

```
$("#mainPage").on("pageshow", function(e) { 
}
```

at the bottom of the body of my index.html file.  And it is from within this function that I am trying to display a custom dialog.  Is this the problem?  The code simply skips over any attempt to call the dialog and continues to run without any errors.

I can incorporate more code (not the full huge app), but don't want to confuse the issue too much.

Comment: are you using phonegap?If not then use this dialog 1)http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/popup/

Comment: how do you call a dialog? post js and html code.

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid, the dialog was working, but while it was opening other code was running.  i solved that using a callback from the dialog. But...  Then I decided the dialog did not give the right feel and have switched to a JQM popup instead.