# How to change text values in confirmation box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A cookie must be set and also confirmed.
However, I want to change the text of the confirmation box? Is there any way?
Like OK=Hello and Cancel=Reset in the example below:
**HTML:**

```
<body onload="checkCookie()"></body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var c_value = document.cookie;
var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
  }
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_value = null;
  }
else
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
  var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
  if (c_end == -1)
    {
    c_end = c_value.length;
    }
  c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
  }
return c_value;
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie()
{
var username=getCookie("username");
if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
      var conf = confirm("Welcome again " + username);
      if(conf==true)
      {
          return false;
      }
      else
      {
          alert("Your cookies have been reset!");
      }
  }
else 
  {
      username=prompt("Please input your name below:","");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
    setCookie("username",username,365);
    }
  }
}
```

In addition, is there any way to be done like this:
When the entered username is set, being also reset while Cancel/Reset is clicked.
I wouldn't complain if somebody uses jQuery to do so though.
Thanks in advance. I will rep who helps me out :)
http://jsfiddle.net/V6LZE/

Comment: No. You can't change the native confirm box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other options using some jQuery plugin, you can edit OK & Cancel button text. Helpful links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/431829/How-to-change-button-text-of-Alert-message-using-j

[Display Yes and No buttons instead of OK and Cancel in Confirm box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445946/display-yes-and-no-buttons-instead-of-ok-and-cancel-in-confirm-box)

jsfiddle.net/taditdash/PHX2Y/

Hope will help!